# Dynamically add padding to nested children using SASS CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to make a directory tree. It will be generating nesting children dynamically. For example here's the HTML

```
    <ul>
    <li>
        <div>test</div>
        <span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div>test1</div>
                    <span>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div>test 2</div>
                                <span>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li> test2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How do I add the SASS CSS to it, that for every nesting LI child, 20px is added. For first level 20, second 40 and so on.. I am trying to add padding directly to each LI, but that basically moves the whole element on the left, I want to keep the div as full width, so I can provide a full width bottom border to it, and just move the contents inside it with padding.

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/Merri/pen/uHkCj)

This one does what I want, but its not dynamic.

I made a JSFiddle link here.
https://jsfiddle.net/h7pbmsh1/1/

Comment: Pls share the css code.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927837/css-counters-incrementing-deeply-nested-lists

Comment: @MarioJuniorTorresPerez Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/h7pbmsh1/1/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking to chain the **[child combinator (`>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)** as such:

```
ul > li > ul > li {
  padding-left: 3em;
}
```

This way, the selector won't target the initial `Main` `<li>` elements, but it will target every single `<li>` element that falls under these top-level `<li>` elements, as can be seen **[here](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/GOrYBy)**.

Note that the above is the 'raw' CSS output. If you specifically want to do it with SASS, you can make use of the child combinator by placing it at the start of a new line, before the inner selector:

```
ul {
  > li {
    > ul {
      > li {
        padding-left: 3em;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The SASS-specific approach can be seen **[here](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/eegPQY)**.

Hope this helps! :)